# Is there a class array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, for-loop, collision

I am making a platformer game and I am wondering if there is a simpler way to store objects in arrays as I use the arrays to check for collision.
Is there any type of array a class can automatically have?

```
//This is with making my own array
var obstacleArray = [];
class Obstacle {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x,
        this.y = y,
        this.width = 50,
        this.height = 50
    }
    
    addToArray() {
        obstacleArray.push(this);
    }
}
obstacle1 = new Obstacle(0, 0);
obstacle2 = new Obstacle(50, 0);
obstacle1.addToArray();
obstacle2.addToArray();
for (let i = 0; i < obstacleArray.length;i++) {
    //check for collision
}
```

Is there some kind of built-in array for a number of variables a class owns so I can quickly check for collision without having to call the addToArray function for every obstacle?

Comment: I do not understand a factory yet, would you please go into more detail or show an example of what a factory is? That would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: you can always search for the phrase *javascript factory pattern* - there's lot's of good tutorials out there ... of course, you could just `obstacleArray.push(this);` in the constructor

Comment: Also, rather than an "external" array, I'd recommend using a class `static` variable .... keeps everything together

Comment: "*is there some kind of built-in array*" - no, and that's a good thing: it would prevent garbage collection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always push to the array in the constructor

Job done :p

Optional but I recommend it: Use a class `static` to hold the array

```js
class Obstacle {
    static obstacleArray = [];
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = 50;
        this.height = 50;
        Obstacle.obstacleArray.push(this);
    }
}
obstacle1 = new Obstacle(0, 0);
obstacle2 = new Obstacle(50, 0);
console.log(Obstacle.obstacleArray);
```

Another interesting option may be to use a Set instead of an array

```js
class Obstacle {
    static obstacles = new Set;
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = 50;
        this.height = 50;
        Obstacle.obstacles.add(this);
    }
    remove() {
        Obstacle.obstacles.delete(this);
    }
}
obstacle1 = new Obstacle(0, 0);
obstacle2 = new Obstacle(50, 0);
[...Obstacle.obstacles.keys()].forEach(obstacle => {
    console.log(obstacle.x);
});
// you can remove an obstacle easily
console.log('removed 1');
obstacle1.remove();
[...Obstacle.obstacles.keys()].forEach(obstacle => {
    console.log(obstacle.x);
});
```